Weird glitch with touchscreen and Angular/Electron app
I have been developing a desktop app with Angular and Electron that must be displayed in a touchscreen (an LG Oled 55" specifically) but everytime I touch the screen, it shows a glitch for a second in other parts of the screen, specifically above other video or animated elements, focus on the top-right part of the image:


Im using "electron": "^30.0.2", "@angular/cli": "^17.3.6", also Im using Chrome in fullscreen.
I tried with css animations, with .gif, with .mp4, and the glitch keeps happening, and Im not finding any similar cases on the internet so im pretty frustrated trying to figuring out if its something software or hardware related, I ran out of ideas...
These are some specifications of my project, if its of any help:
The config in main.js
function createWindow () {

  const {width, height} = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize


  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width,
    height,
    fullscreen: true,
    icon: './src/assets/img/icon.ico',
    webPreferences: {
     
      nodeIntegration: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: true
  })

  try {
    require('electron-reloader')(module)
    mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:4200/")
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  } catch {
    mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
    mainWindow.loadFile(`dist/browser/index.html`)
  }

  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('app-ready');
  });


  

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null

  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})

